# Centering the content of a div in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying various combinations for the past one two hours and I am unable to get this basic thing right. I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have an image and a login dialog just beneath it.[image]

I took the basic boiler plate code from Bootstrap 4 and tried to do alignment using

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment
  but in vain. I request you to tell me what part I a missing.

Here is my html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <title>Hey - A group chat messenger!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="hey_logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Google</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <small id="subtextMessage" class="form-text text-muted">Say Hey! to new beginnings</small>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 1):

The above problem can be resolved by using a separate row with centre-aligned content for each element (image, button, text) inside a column.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <title>Hey - A group chat messenger!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <img src="/hey-logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Google</button>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <small id="subtextMessage" class="form-text text-muted">Say Hey! to new beginnings</small>                    
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This worked. But I have two questions. 1. I would like to bring the image vertificaly centered as well. If I use four <BR> tags, I get the desired result. Is this OK interms of UI development or are there better alternatives for moving the image vertically down?. 2. Whlie your solution works, I am unable to understand why mine did not work. Can you shed some notes on it.

Comment: The image on my computer might have worked because its original width must have closely matched the width of the containing div. This must be a coincidence! The size of the image plays a critical role. Therefore, it is a common practice to set bounds on height and width of image using the max-width, min-width, max-height and min-height css attributes.  Also, the other recommended practice is to replace <br> tags with either 'padding' or 'margin' attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A button is an inline-block element in Bootstrap. Try using the text-center.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Google</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it looks not fine (for example the image is not symettric), then give the col-4 some padding on the left or right side.